# Minecraft - Making mobs hostile to other mobs using command block

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

On our minecraft realm I am a necromancer. Using the /team command I control hostile mobs to attack other players.

I was hoping to make a way to make my wither skeletons and vex attack other mobs.

If anyone has any ideas to make this possible using command blocks please let me know.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. This question needs more focus on programming/scripting part of problem to be suitable for this site. Also you should show script/code you tried so far and where you did get stuck. Even with those details question about modding Minecraft often pop on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) SE, so it might be better to ask there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming. Post on [gaming.se] instead.